# Can end statement replace endfor statement in Octave?

Tags: for-loop, octave

This [link](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/The-for-Statement.html) illustrates that we should use `endfor` statement to close the scope of `for` loop.

But replacing it with `end` results into the same behavior.

Does using `end` rather than `endfor` have any unexpected side effects?

Comment: So you've answered your own question?

Comment: Is there any difference between two that I am unaware of?

Comment: You should add that to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`end` is synonymous with `endfor` when closing a `for` loop.

The only side effect of using `end` is that your code will also be compatible with MATLAB, as `endfor` is an extension of the language invented by Octave. I recommend that you do not use `endfor` and the like (`endif`, `endfunction`, `endswitch`, `endwhile`).

Answer (score 7):

In practice I mostly agree with Cris' answer, and I follow the same advice in principle. However, I feel a need to play devil's advocate here, because it makes it sound like the octave developer's decision to provide these keywords was misguided, when actually there is good reason, and knowing the benefits of using endfor, endif  allows you to make an informed decision on when and why to avoid them.

Allow me to demonstrate their usefulness with an example:

```
function f(a)
    if a == 1
       disp('a == 1')
    else if a == 2
       disp('a == 2')
    else
       disp('a == 3')
    end
    disp('do some very important thing here that absolutely must be done always')
end
```

Can you spot the subtle but deadly bug here?

Whereas if you try to run this code:

```
function f(a)
    if a == 1
       disp('a == 1')
    else if a == 2
       disp('a == 2')
    else
       disp('a == 3')
    endif
    disp('do important thing')
endfunction
```

octave will immediately warn you that something is awfully wrong, and it will stop you from shooting yourself on the foot.

There are many other situations where endifs and endfors would protect you when simple `end` wouldn't. And, at the very least, they provide a very strong visual signposting of where you are in the code (did I just close that for loop, or did I just exit an if block). Especially given the state of most academic code out there, which is usually a bunch of unindented spaghetti code with lots of nested `if` and `for` blocks that goes on for miles in a single file. Chances are if you follow good software engineering principles, clean, modular, properly indented code, then the extra layer of protection added by writing `endfor` instead of `end` is probably overkill. But just because this is the case doesn't mean they're not there for good reason.

But, I agree, if you desire matlab compatibility, and you probably do, then it's best you use the 'slightly less safe but ultimately compatible' version.

Ironically, I often find myself writing code that looks like this:

```
if something
  % large block of code here
end % if
```

just to be matlab compatible, but still make it visually clear that the block that just closed was actually an if block.

Comment: That’s a nice argument. Thank you for sharing your point of view! I think linters should be able to avoid this type of error, but you are 100% right about most MATLAB/Octave code being academic spaghetti with inconsistent indentation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, and like I said, I was playing devil's advocate, I'm actually in the same camp as you when it comes to advising people to use end vs endfor, hahah. (having said that, the bug above would not be picked up by a linter, since it's a logical bug, but otherwise completely valid matlab code)

Comment: A good linter would pick up that the functional nesting doesn’t match the indenting. I don’t know if any MATLAB linters pay attention to that, but my C++ editor certainly lets me know if indenting is wrong.

Comment: @SauravSahu: in that example, `else if` starts an new `if` statement. There are two `if` statements ended with an `end`. There is no `end` for `function`, but that is legal in MATLAB. The code is meant to use `elseif` rather than `else if`.

Comment: @SauravSahu try running the function with f(1) and see if the "really important thing that should always happen" happens :)

Comment: Just to followup on this old post. I tried both versions of this example function in Octave 7.1.0 and they both give the same warning about "endif command matched by endfunction".  It looks like the most recent version of Octave interprets this as an "endif" whether you use "endif" or "end" in this example.

Comment: @Sanjo I tried it on 7.1.0 too and it's not the case. I would have been very surprised if it were, since that would be a change in the language ... you probably just copied something wrong :)