# How can I run a MATLAB script in Python without having MATLAB installed

Tags: python, matlab

I'd like to assess video quality using RAPIQUE. This program is implemented in MATLAB, however I do not have a MATLAB installation.

Can I run MATLAB's .m file in Python without having MATLAB installed?

RAPIQUE:
vztu/RAPIQUE: [IEEE OJSP'2021] "RAPIQUE: Rapid and Accurate Video Quality Prediction of User Generated Content", Zhengzhong Tu, Xiangxu Yu, Yilin Wang, Neil Birkbeck, Balu Adsumilli, Alan C. Bovik (github.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: you cannot.

You need to have a working, licensed MATLAB installation, which will be called in the background. Without a working, licensed MATLAB installation you cannot run MATLAB code.
As MATLAB is proprietary, there are only three ways to run MATLAB code: by running the code from the MATLAB IDE (with a valid license of course), running it via the MATLAB engine (through Python, from a terminal with `-nodisplay` etc), or by compiling it to an executable file with the [MATLAB compiler](https://mathworks.com/products/compiler.html).

A possible workaround would be to export your MATLAB code to C/C++ using the [MATLAB Coder](https://mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html). You can then run the C/C++ code in whatever editor you like. Alternatively you could check whether the program translates easily into [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index), which is free.

The proper solution, however, would be to translate the actual code to Python.

Comment: A while since I've used Octave, but pretty sure `end` is still a valid keyword and `endfunction`/`endif` are optional syntax for readability. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151768/can-end-statement-replace-endfor-statement-in-octave#:~:text=end%20is%20synonymous%20with%20endfor,endfunction%20%2C%20endswitch%20%2C%20endwhile%20))

Comment: @Wolfie thanks, that makes that option even better